# Why GMSMapView is not set at the appropriate coordinate?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

This might be a frequently asked question, but believe it or not, I didn't find an answer that helped me fix my issue.

Nevertheless I tried multiple solutions and I don't understand why sometimes the camera of the `GMSMapView` object does not initialize at the right position.

I have dragged an `UIView` in my `UIViewController` scene from the Interface Builder, set it as `GMSMapView` object.

Here is my setCamera method :

```
private func setCamera(lat: Double, long: Double, zoom: Float) {

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: zoom)
    mapView.camera = camera
    mapView.setMinZoom(5, maxZoom: 15)
}
```

I tried to call it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` it's the same behavior.

1 out of 5 launches (approximately), the camera is not centered at the right coordinate, it feels like the `GMSMapView` is initialized with random camera.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my initialization of GMSMapView:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: myLocation.coordinate, 
                                      zoom: mapDefaultZoom)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, 
                             camera: camera)
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

It's update of the camera position:

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds().includingCoordinate(position)
let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, 
                                 withPadding: 60)
mapView.animate(with: update)
```

Hope, it will help you.

Comment: What if I want to keep a reference of the mapView. Why the initialization has not the same behavior when I have a GMSMapView outlet ?